iframe anchor tag url opening in a new page with blank content
I have an iframe with an anchor tag inside of it
<iframe class="active" scrolling="no" src="{bodyUrl}" sandbox="allow-top-navigation allow-same-origin allow-forms allow-popups"><a data-fr-linked="true" href="https://example.com/new/Home/Link?te=st" id="isPasted" target="_blank">Navigate</a></iframe>

My issue is that a user upon following this url, a new tab opens, but the new tab page remains white, blank.
In Chrome i get this error

Blocked script execution in '' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set.

Now I know for a fact if I add allow-scripts to the sandbox property the page will load, but I need an alternative way which would allow a user's interaction following the url to allow that page to open?
I know if I
Correct me if I'm wrong. The new page has scripts attached to it and even though we open a new window from the iframe, the sandbox property still applies? That's why we see the error?
The issue is I don't have access to the new page's source code.

If you want markup in between the tags of an <iframe> you need to use the doc-src attribute/property.

What you have shown us, is a link as alternate content for browsers to display, if they can't display iframes - is that really your situation here? Or are you actually rather asking about a link in a document you loaded into the iframe? Please clarify.

Assuming that you actually mean a link inside the iframe-d document - you'll need to set the allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox flag, so that this "popup" doesn't inherit the restrictions from the iframe.

@C3roe. It's a link inside the iframe element.
I've just tried the allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox and it does indeed work. Thank you for showing that to me.
However, can you imagine a scenario where this could be exploited?
That's the main reason allow-scripts was not used.

Not using allow-scripts, means the document loaded into the iframe would not be allowed to execute any scripts - and that will stay that way. And for the link opened in a new window, you don't want to apply any restrictions, correct?

The overwhelming majority of users will see it as all modern browsers support iframes. I think I'm not explaining the issue properly.
When the user follows the anchor tag url it leads them to a new page which is blank.
'allow-scripts' works, but we don't want to allow users to do xss and get the cookies, so we don't use it.
I'm now looking at the 'allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox' and it also works, it helps with displaying the new tab content ( which came from following the url as we have target="_blank").
I'm now wondering is it dangerous to 'allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox'
